# php - encode mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to save a mySQL-query in a json file with php.
To get data from the query result I do

```
$resArray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resArray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($resArray);
```

Some fields may contain 'ä', 'ö' and 'ü'. 
For example I have 
`"category":"Stöcke"`.
When json_encode the result array, fields with ä, ö and ü will be encoded as null, e.g. `"category":null` 
**How to correctly encode all resultsets to save the json correct and show all fields and contents?**

Comment: have you tried `json_encode($resArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: does not work with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

Comment: okay, does work with my combined solution (see answers) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. with all answers from you I created the solution!
Thanks to everyone, I'm combining `utf8_encode` for every row field with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` for `json_encode`:

```
// get result from query
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

        // get infos for all columns
        $columnInfos = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);


        // create an array
        $resArray = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            foreach ($columnInfos as $info) {
                $row[$info->name] = utf8_encode($row[$info->name]);
            }
            $resArray[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($resArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Cool, if you ever need something that will work on systems pre`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` (PHP 5.4+) the function on my answer will do the trick ;)

Comment: yes. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> json_encode() only supports UTF-8 encoding. [Read this.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

So either you switch the project to UTF-8 or you make sure you `utf8_encode()` any string before using `json_encode()`.